# Is it possible to learn many languages at the same time and become fluent in all of them?

Tags: multiple-languages

I think the answer would be yes for the first part of my question, but I am not sure what it would be if we seek fluency in all languages that we learn at the same time (maybe 2 or 3 languages).

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between fluency and proficiency? Can you please clarify whether your question is about *proficiency* (which is more general, i.e. the *level* you reach) or just about the more specific aspect know as *fluency* (which is often contrasted with accuracy)?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Your question led me to do some search to understand deeply the difference between *fluency* and *proficiency* and I can confirm that my question is about *fluency*. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in fact, [American teenager Tim Doner](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FOiXtWcQ8GI) could speak 20 languages by the time he graduated high school. He studied several languages simultaneously and is fluent in some of them, the ones he has had the most experience with. This should go without saying, but doing what he did requires an immense amount of dedication.

Comment: Note that "fluency" is a very vague concept, so the statement that he's fluent says very little. For some people A2/B1 may mean fluent, for others the standard for fluency is around C2.

Comment: @michau I agree, but the questions asks: is it possible to become fluent, and while Tim might not be fluent in every language he speaks, he definitely is fluent in some.

Comment: Well, in the answer you wrote "and is fluent in *all* of them"...

Comment: @michau point taken, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: My criterion for **proficiency** (not *fluency* as I wrote in a previous comment) is C1 in the CEFR. This is the level required to pass several proficiency tests for access to universities in foreign countries, e.g. TestDaF in Germany. C2 is often described as "near native", but you don't need to reach that level to be fluent, IMHO.